A white circle with 20% transparency on the jumbotron
I'm using bootstrap on my website and I saw something cool on other website. They have like a 20% transparent circle that makes white shadow on fully dark background.

I'm also asking how can I use bootstrap to make my jumbotron not that high because currently is almost on the navbar. I need it set padding-top like to 15% but using Bootstrap only.


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-between py-5">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center col-md-3 mb-2 mb-md-0 nav-brand">
      <p>Something will be here!</p>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 mb-md-0 d-flex align-items-center ms-md-3">
      <li class="px-2">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Test 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="px-2">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Test 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="px-2">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Test 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="px-2">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Test 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="col-md-3 text-end nav-btn">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link px-2">Test 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- need to change padding-top: 15% to use bootstrap only for it -->
  <div class="row align-items-start" style="padding-top: 15% !important;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
        <h1>Test 6!</h1>
      </div>

      <p> Hello world </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Please tag your Bootstrap version and ask just one question per post. See [ask] and take the [tour].

@JayCravens I figured it out. Adding !important in css will overwrite this. Thanks.

If you have found a solution, please post it below and accept the answer or delete your post.
